# "Something Bad Happened" to All the Stuff

Tags: bug, status-completed, 500-server-error

Just now, I was getting this error whenever I tried to view a question or go to ask a question here to complain that I couldn't view questions:

> [image]

I also saw this in an incognito window, where I wouldn't be logged in.

I was however, able to post an answer (and possibly a comment) on a page I already had loaded when this was happening. Fortunately, the system prevented me from posting duplicate answers.

So I'm reporting that this happened.

Comment: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1057385414770769926

Answer (score 6):

Copying [my answer from MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/376010/426671):

> There was a bad build that was impacting the display [of some
>   questions](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1057385414770769926).
>   The build was rolled back and pages should be loading normally again.
>
> We're still investigating the bug that caused the problem in the first place, but things should be working fine now.